# Pandas to_sql - NotImplementedError?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with the following columns in it:

```
account_number                 int64
prediction                     int64
probability_of_prediction    float64
probability_of_redemption    float64
```

The dataframe is dtype: object.

I want to upload its data into a table in a DB2 database. The table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
(
ACCOUNT_NUMBER              INT,
PREDICTION                  INT,
PROBABILITY_OF_PREDICTION   DECIMAL(5,2),
PROBABILITY_OF_REDEMPTION   DECIMAL(5,2)
)
IN MYSCHEMA
COMPRESS YES
;
```

This is the code I'm using for the upload:

```
df.to_sql(name = "mytable", con = connection, schema = "myschema", if_exists = 'replace', index = False, chunksize = 1000, method = "multi")
```

However, it fails with the following message, which isn't particularly informative:

```
NotImplementedError
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong, please?

Edit: As requested, here's the full error message:

```
ERROR:root:Problem:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My_filepath\my_script.py", line 185, in <module>
    modelling()
  File "C:\My_filepath\my_script.py", line 164, in modelling
    df.to_sql(name = "mytable", con = connection, schema = "myschema", if_exists = 'replace', index = False, chunksize = 1000, method = "multi")
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2951, in to_sql
    return sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 697, in to_sql
    return pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1729, in to_sql
    table = self.prep_table(
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1628, in prep_table
    table.create()
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 835, in create
    self.pd_sql.drop_table(self.name, self.schema)
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1787, in drop_table
    self.meta.reflect(bind=self.connectable, only=[table_name], schema=schema)
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 4860, in reflect
    Table(name, self, **reflect_opts)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 616, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 611, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 686, in _init
    self._autoload(
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 721, in _autoload
    conn_insp.reflect_table(
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py", line 791, in reflect_table
    self._reflect_pk(
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py", line 920, in _reflect_pk
    pk_cons = self.get_pk_constraint(
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py", line 528, in get_pk_constraint
    return self.dialect.get_pk_constraint(
  File "C:\My_filepath\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\interfaces.py", line 285, in get_pk_constraint
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: When posting about an error, you should show the entire stack trace.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) for the `schema` parameter:  Specify the schema (if database flavor supports this). Perhaps the flavor you're using doesn't support it.

Comment: @Joe I've added this to the original post.

Comment: do you use SQL Alchemy?. to be able to use to_sql you need an sql alchemy. As per the documentation

Comment: @Joe I think the database does support this; the to_sql statement I'm using is one that I've used successfully in the past to load data from other dataframes to other tables within the same schema.

Comment: @AtanasAtanasov Yes, I import sqlalchemy earlier in the script and use it to create a connection via the sqlalchemy.create_engine function; this engine is stored as a variable named 'connection' which is used in the to_sql statement. This method has worked successfully in the past.

Comment: from the stacktrace it either seems like a bug in the sqlalchemy as it can't get the constraints for the Primariy keys on your table. Or it is casesensive. Have you tried uppercasing the shema and table name  and column names in the python code?

Comment: The error comes from line 1361 of [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/interfaces.py), but I'm not familiar with the package, so I can't say anything else about it.